# Zipping XML file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I need to create a xml file and then zip and upload.
I am able to create xml file and upload but fail to zip the file.
Can we zip xml files using Jmeter. Please let me know if anyone has a working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of archiving the file in JMeter, the easiest is calling 3rd-party program like zip or [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) console archiver using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler).

Alternatively you can use

- [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- and [java.util.zip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) API

for generating a zip archive on the fly programmatically, example code would be something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def xml = new File('/path/to/your/file.xml')

def zip = new File('/path/to/created/archive.zip')

def out = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zip))

out.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(xml.getName()))

xml.withInputStream {
    IOUtils.copy(it, out)
}

IOUtils.closeQuietly(out)
```